cURL with SOCKS5 NordVPN proxy
I paid for NordVPN, because I want to use one solution which is not yet available here in this region. Sadly I always get this error from the script: "cURL request failed, error = couldn't connect to host;"
I tried with a very verbose version, but nothing seems to work. I even tried with socks5:// and with socks5h:// , same. Do I have to set up semething else if I want to use SOCKS5 proxy with cURL or could this a NordVPN issue? The generated service username and passwors seems to work, because in qBittorrent the traffic is okay after SOCKS5 configuration. Sadly the helpdesk can't help with these kind of questions.
function run_curl_debug($url,$fields=null,$method=null,$file=null)
{

    $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';
    $timeout= 240;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5h://***yP8hUyvxT6D**********:***xBniWy6VFXQ**********@los-angeles.us.socks.nordhold.net:1080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$content){
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        die("cURL request failed, error = {$error}; info = " . print_r($info, true));
    }
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        return $content;        
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $response;
}

